# Make global module in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to make a module to be accessible globally (window). Just like `jQuery`. How can I do that in webpack?

If I have some file in `src` folder then how can I access globally.

Answer (score 0):

Making a JavaScript module global doesn't require you to change your Webpack setup. Instead, you can simply create the src file as a [JavaScript Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

The linked MDN page gives detailed information about how this works and how to do it. As you can see, the JavaScript Modules system is supported by all modern browsers, which is why there is no need for any Webpack setup just to use a module.

[image]

**EDIT** given the nature of my reply, I have not answered the question directly. If you still wish to use Webpack, the Webpack documentation gives information on making things global. Such as [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/). Please note, you will see on that page that they actually try to dissuade you from making things global. Depending on your case, there may be relevant warnings here against this approach.

Comment: And if I want to make entry file as global in webpack